# How to initiate click before page is fully loaded

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a problem with Selenium webdriver where a page continues to load even though visibly the page has loaded and the button I want to click on the page is now available.

I've used both implicit and explicit wait for the page to load but with no success.

How can I force the driver to click a button on a page which has not completed loading?

A snippet of my explicit wait code:

```
    myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//button[@type='submit'])[2]")));
    myDynamicElement.click();
```

Thanks

Added HTML:

```
    </div>

    <div class="first-message-form">

        <form role="form" action="/signup/first-message" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">

                <textarea id="message_message" name="message[message]"    class="form-control"></textarea>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Post to others</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Skip</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

The "Skip" button is the one I am trying to click.

Comment: What is the error? and, can you provide little more code with the navigation to the site?

Comment: There is no error. My script just stops running as the page is still loading. I don't want to wait for the page to complete loading. I want to go ahead and click the button which is available even though the page has not completed loading.

Comment: Can you provide the `html` of the button you want to click and to clarify what's going wrong I am curious to see your test code as well.

Comment: I've added the HTML. I've updated the code as well. What other code are you after?

Comment: I wanna investigate the reason why your page keeps loading and the code  how you instantiate the driver and navigate to the page.

Comment: And, click on `Skip` button?

Comment: Unfortunately the website is behind a firewall so you won't be able to access it. I've written quite a lot of code so I am not sure what part you're after. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would execute `javascript` on that button. I am assuming you are using selenium java bindings since you never mentioned that.

```
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"[type='submit'][class='btn btn-default btn-lg']\").click();");
```

This script should click on `Skip` button

I actually never faced any issue where the page never finishes loading. That's why I was curious to see if you are doing something you should not be doing while navigating to the `url`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Saifur. I will try it and see if it works.

Comment: Just tried this and got the following error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: What language you are using?

Comment: I'm using Java in Eclipse

Comment: Seen and trying now. Thanks again. Fingers crossed it works this time.

Comment: I'm afraid this did not work. Stuck with the same problem as the page continues to load and the button is not clicked.

Comment: I don't think there is any other solution that selenium can provide. Because if the `Dom` is not loaded properly `selenium` won't find the element. You need to investigate why the page never stops loading. Can't really provide any more help because I don't know how the code was written that can go wrong.

Comment: Also, try this when you think you are comfortable to stop the webpage from loading `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.stop");` and then execute the code I provide

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try as well. But you raised a good point as to why the page is not loading completely. I will talk to the developers about this.

Comment: Just to let you guys know we found the problem with why the page was not loading and the developers fixed it. It was a genuine issue. :-)

Comment: I don't know why I got a negative vote for this answer!!

Answer (score 0):

In WebDriver [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) you can find the following:

> Dependent on several factors, including the OS/Browser combination,
>   WebDriver may or may not wait for the page to load. In some
>   circumstances, WebDriver may return control before the page has
>   finished, or even started, loading. To ensure robustness, you need to
>   wait for the element(s) to exist in the page using Explicit and
>   Implicit Waits.

This means that you can't ensure the driver behaviour in this case. Therefore the stable test will probably the one that will work when the page is loaded.