# Click button before page is fully loaded

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I click a button on a page before it's fully loaded? I know I can set the timeout with `driver.set_page_load_timeout(400)`, but this page is taking a very long time to load, and I don't need it loaded in order to proceed.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
time.sleep(2)          # wait a few seconds to make sure button exists
driver.stop_loading()  # or similar?
button.click()         # navigate to next page
```

Comment: I got intrigued by your question and got into these 2 links: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28312567/3846228) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702637/selenium-click-without-waiting-for-page-to-load-python). Maybe they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the page from loading by pressing the `ESC` key.

In Ruby:

```
//Sleep
@driver.action.send_keys(:esc).perform
//Button click
```

If you can figure out the equivalent code in python it'll work.
Not sure but it should be something like this:

```
time.sleep(2)  
ActionChains(driver) \
   .send_keys(Keys.ESC) \
   .perform()
button.click()
```